# Как побороть UnsupportedOperationException: null в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Столкнулся с довольно странной проблемой. Имеется entity User и объекты этого класса нужно связать друг с другом через many-to-many relationship. Соответственно, помимо основной таблицы "user" должны появиться еще 2 таблицы "customer_authors" "author_customers"

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    // ID пользователя
    private Long userId;


    // "customer_authors"
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_authors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
    private List<User> authorsList = new ArrayList<>();

    // "author_customers"
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "author_customers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"))
    private List<User> customersList = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters, setters and other data.
}
```

Нигде в моем коде не используется Arrays asList() / не создается список с фиксированным размером. Именно, это является причиной подобной ошибки согласно поиску в гугл и stackoverflow...

В моем случае, если в @Service UserService использовать подобный код:

```
user.setUserEmail(userEmail);
user.setUserPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userPassword));
userRepository.save(user);

User referrer = userRepository.findUserByUserId(referrerId);
referrer.getAuthorsList().add(user);
userRepository.save(referrer);
```

то получаю соответствующую ошибку -

```
UnsupportedOperationException

// excerpt
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at info.md7.textpool.services.UserService.addUser(UserService.java:252) ~[classes/:na]
  at info.md7.textpool.controllers.UserController.userRegistration(UserController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
```

Но при этом, если для теста в контроллере использовать что-то подобное:

```
User customer = (User) userService.findUserByEmail(currentUser.getUsername());
    User author = userRepository.findByUserEmail("sukkivulmo@desoz.com");
    customer.getAuthorsList().add(author);
    userRepository.save(author);
```

то действительно, в таблицу добавляется нужная информация ID реферрера и ID пользователя.

В чем может быть заключаться ошибка? Может быть, кто-то сталкивался с этим и знает, как исправить? Заранее благодарю!

Полный сниппет метода из UserService:

```
public boolean addUser(  //todo добавить тип работы
          String userFullname,
          String userEmail,
          String userPassword,
          String prefLangs,
          String prefCats,
          Double paymentCost,
          String paymentMethod,
          String paymentWallet,
          Long referrerId,
          User user
  ) throws MessagingException {

    User userFromDbEmail = userRepository.findByUserEmail(userEmail);
    User referrer = userRepository.findUserByUserId(referrerId);

    if(userFromDbEmail != null) {
      return false;
    }

    /*
     * Проверяем наличие данных в полях prefLang, prefCats, paymentCost, paymentMethod, paymentWallet.
     * И если они имеются в одном из полей, то регистрируем пользователя, как Автора.
     * В противном случае, создаем нового Заказчика.
     *
     */

    if(
        prefLangs != null && !prefLangs.isEmpty() ||
        prefCats != null && !prefCats.isEmpty() ||
        paymentCost != null ||
        paymentMethod != null && !paymentMethod.isEmpty() ||
        paymentWallet != null && !paymentWallet.isEmpty()
    ) {

      user.setUserFullname(userFullname);
      user.setUserEmail(userEmail);
      user.setUserPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userPassword));
      user.setRegDate(LocalDateTime.now());
      user.setUserActive(false);
      user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.AUTHOR));
      user.setActivationCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      user.setUserMode("author");
      user.setReceiveEmails(true);

      // Если пользователь был приглашен, то находим реферрера и добавлем в его список нового пользователя
      User referrer = userRepository.findUserByUserId(referrerId);
      user.setReferrerId(referrer);

      userRepository.save(user);


      /*  Добавляем метаданные для юзера
          С связи с особенностями верстки, данные скриптом вставляю в hidden input поле, после чего
          получаю String разделенный запятыми и разобрав добавляю данные в user_meta
       */
      assert prefLangs != null;
      String[] prefLang = prefLangs.split(",");
      for (String metaValue : prefLang) {
        UserMeta userMeta = new UserMeta();
        String metaKey = "prefLang";
        userMeta.setMetaKey(metaKey);
        userMeta.setMetaValue(metaValue);
        userMeta.setUser(user);
        userMetaRepository.save(userMeta);
      }

      assert prefCats != null;
      String[] prefCat = prefCats.split(",");
      for (String metaValue : prefCat) {
        UserMeta userMeta = new UserMeta();
        String metaKey = "prefCat";
        userMeta.setMetaKey(metaKey);
        userMeta.setMetaValue(metaValue);
        userMeta.setUser(user);
        userMetaRepository.save(userMeta);
      }

      UserMeta paymentMeta = new UserMeta();
      paymentMeta.setMetaKey(paymentMethod);
      paymentMeta.setMetaValue(paymentWallet);
      paymentMeta.setUser(user);
      userMetaRepository.save(paymentMeta);

      if(paymentCost != null) {
        UserMeta paymentCostMeta = new UserMeta();
        paymentCostMeta.setMetaKey("paymentCost");
        paymentCostMeta.setMetaValue(paymentCost.toString());
        paymentCostMeta.setUser(user);
        userMetaRepository.save(paymentCostMeta);
      }


      referrer.getAuthorsList().add(user);
      userRepository.save(referrer);

    } else {

      user.setUserFullname(userFullname);
      user.setUserEmail(userEmail);
      user.setUserPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userPassword));
      user.setRegDate(LocalDateTime.now());
      user.setUserActive(false);
      user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.CUSTOMER));
      user.setActivationCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      user.setUserMode("customer");
      user.setReceiveEmails(true);

      // Если пользователь был приглашен, то находим реферрера и добавлем в его список нового пользователя
      User referrer = userRepository.findUserByUserId(referrerId);
      user.setReferrerId(referrer);

      userRepository.save(user);


      referrer.getCustomersList().add(user);
      userRepository.save(referrer);

    }

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: `2 таблицы "customer_authors" "author_customers"`...а одной вам недостаточно будет?...либо Вы с именами напутали либо со структурой...по виду вы просто создаете зеркальную связь зачем-то

Comment: Вы ссылаетесь сами на себя и для трёх разных по смыслу сущности `пользователь`, `автор`, `клиент` используете всё того же пользователя...Почему Вам не создать отдельно Клиента и отдельно Автора которые будут ссылаться на пользователя?..мне тяжело понять что Вы хотите сделать

Comment: На самом деле, изначально так и было задумано и 2 сущности Author&Customer наследовались от родителя User. Но с учетом особенностей задачи, Author может являться Customer, также, как Customer быть Author. Было решено при регистрации создавать одного пользователя, а разграничивать уже по правам.  Что касается того достаточно ли одной таблицы или нет, то нет. В идеале мне нужны 3 таблицы User, где хранятся юзеры,а также 2 таблицы c ManyToMany, для того, чтобы создать списки Авторы реферрера и Клиенты реферрера. Т.е. текущая структура устраивает, но не могу понять почему в Service получаю ошибку

Comment: Для того чтобы проанализировать ошибку, лично мне, недостаточно предоставленного кода...  если есть ссылка на гитхаб могу посмотреть.

Comment: Ну так, а почему бы вам в таком случае просто не сделать таблицу с ролями и присваивать роли пользователю?.. Это исключительно классическое решение.

Comment: Все верно, таблица с ролями имеется. Тут задача совсем в другом... Надо маппить саму же сущность используя ManyToMany, но при этом если получить список где-нибудь в другом методе, то все работает. А если попытаться в методе, где сохраняется save(user), а потом save(referrer), то возникает ошибка. Т.е. как я понял в одном методе невозможно сохранять одновременно 2 объекта?

Comment: `как я понял в одном методе невозможно сохранять одновременно 2 объекта` - нет, таких ограничений нет и быть не может.

Comment: `Надо маппить саму же сущность используя ManyToMany`, эту задачу в такой постановке поставил кто-то извне или же вы сами для себя так её поставили?

Comment: Я не могу понять как это должно работать. Как в реальном мире между собой связаны пользователь, клиент и автор? Кто на кого и как ссылается в этих двух таблицах? Приведите конкретные кейсы на примере `Клиент Иванов В.П.`, `Пользователь Сидоров Г.М.` и `Автор Петров Н.Ф.`

Comment: Прежде всего позвольте поблагодарить за то, что пытаетесь помочь) Итак, постараюсь привести примеры...  Есть сайт, где пользователи могут регистрироваться и заказывать или писать статьи. Т.е. пользователь может быть как автором, так и заказчиком. Изначально, я создавал 2 сущности Author & Customer, которые наследовались от User. Но тут мы упираемся в то, что если пользователь "станет" заказчиком или автором, то для него нужно создавать дополнительную сущность Author / Customer.  Чтобы избежать этого было принято решение не использовать доп. сущности, а создавать обычного юзера.

Comment: Итак, предположим что на сайте зарегистрирован заказчик Иванов. По реф. ссылке он может пригласить автора Сидорова. После регистрации Сидорова нужно добавить его в список авторов Иванова (тут и нужна ManyToMany), так как Иванов может приглашать много авторов. Также, как и Сидоров, будучи клиентов или автором может приглашать своих авторов или заказчиков соответственно. Если использовать одну сущность User + маппить самого себя по типу ManyToMany, то я могу "достичь" желаемого результата. Но при попытке добавить Сидорова в список Иванова появляется исключение.

Comment: Исключение UnsupportedOperationException появляется только, если при регистрации Сидорова получить список Иванова и помимо сохранения / создания профиля для Сидорова, также сохранить Иванова. Выше предоставил весь код регистрации. Ошибка возникает при выполнении referrer.getAuthorsList().add(user);
userRepository.save(referrer);  именно в этом методе.В связи с недостаточностью опыта и знаний, не знаю в чем может заключаться проблема в данном случае

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Откуда взялся UnsupportedOperationException?**

Коллекции в Java могут иметь необязательные для реализации методы.
При вызове метода, имплементация которого не предусмотрена в данной реализации выбрасывается `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
public interface Iterator<E> {
    //...
    default void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
    }
    //...
}
```

Наличие подобных методов в интерфейсе может вызвать недоумение, однако в данном случае, насколько я понимаю, это вызвано поддержкой обратной совместимости с более старыми версиями Java.

Как уже говорилось другими участниками, коллекции могут быть изменяемыми и неизменяемыми. Однако, вопреки общему мнению в данном случае исключение возникает не из-за использования `Arrays.asList`(автор явно инициализирует поля новым объектом `ArrayList'а`).
Хотя это было очень-очень близко и копать явно нужно было в эту сторону.

К сожалению, всё внимание было приковано к двум полям: `authorsList` и `customersList`.
Там были очень сомнительные зеркальные связи, да ещё и с каскадными операциями, которые в данном конкретном случае явно не могли быть применены в том виде. Более того при удалении `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` ошибка пропадала. К ним мы вернемся позже.

Ошибка была куда прозаичнее:

```
user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.AUTHOR));
```

Автор явно создаёт синглтон(немодифицируемую коллекцию) и передаёт его в список ролей.

После чего данный объект успешно сохраняется.

Ошибка же возникает после того как мы добавляем данного пользователя в список приглашенных клиентов другого пользователя и сохраняем второго пользователя(приглашающего), который был предварительно получен с помощью hibernate.

Сохранив второго пользователя и его связь с первым, hibernate смотрит на `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` над `customersList` и начинает обновлять объект первого пользователя, который лежал в данном списке. Перезаписывает все поля, встречающиеся в полях коллекции hibernate чистит после чего извлекает в них данные заново. И так он доходит до поля `roles` с синглтоном, который лежит в первом пользователе, который в свою очередь лежит внутри списка второго пользователя. Пытается очистить его и получает `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Чтобы исправить это достаточно просто написать:

```
  user.getRoles().add(Role.AUTHOR);
```

И `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` в данном случае не при чем.
Тем не менее его оставлять так нельзя. Потому что, при удалении  приглашающего пользователя автоматически будут удалены и все авторы и клиенты, что как мне кажется не соответствует замыслам автора.

Над данными двумя полями(`authorsList` и  `customersList`) стоит как минимум поставить

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, targetEntity = User.class)
```

А если говорить честно, то данные поля являются избыточными и от них можно просто избавиться.
Ведь для каждого приглашенного пользователя мы устанавливаем referrer(пригласившего пользователя).
Соответственно мы можем либо добавить обратное свойство `invitedUsers` и отфильтровать его по роли.
Либо просто выбрать пользователей по referrer'у и роли.

Comment: Доброго дня! Позвольте, еще раз поблагодарить Вас за грамотный ответ и помощь! Признаюсь, я бы не разобрался сам, особенно, если учесть тот факт, что 90% искомых результатов в поисковых системах сводится к тому, что причиной данной ошибки является создание списка с фиксированным размером.

Comment: @OrkhanHasanli, как не горько признавать, но 90% были правы). Просто ваш список фиксированного размера был создан не таким избитым способом и не там где его ожидали. Ну и по себе скажу, что когда не знаешь как что-то работает, некому подсказать и негде посмотреть - нужно смотреть исходный код. Он может рассказать гораздо больше и гораздо точнее. Плюс в Intellij IDEA есть прекрасный дебаггер, которым можно пользоваться. Он тоже вносит ясность в трудных случаях. Им стоит научиться пользоваться. В любом случае удачи вам ;-)

Comment: Благодарю. Взаимно)

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону **Array list** он возвращает `list`, `Arrays.asList` возвращает список фиксированного размера, в который нельзя добавлять элементы. Изменяемый список можно создать как-то так

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10,20,60,30,22,70,89));
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Тут проблема в том, что я использую ArrayList<>, а не Arrays.asList. Я прочитал английскую версию stackoverflow и действительно, в 90% случаев эта ошибка возникает именно по  причине, которую вы указали.

Comment: @OrkhanHasanli не забудьте принять ответ если он решил вашу проблему

Comment: Один из пользователей уже решил проблему и даже исправил. Я приму его ответ в качестве решения. Еще раз спасибо!